# Python: Transform Dataframe from list of dates to a Date From & Date To format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks as follows:

```
+------------+------+-------+
| Date       | Item | Value |
+------------+------+-------+
| 2020-01-01 | A    | 100   |
+------------+------+-------+
| 2020-01-01 | B    | 80    |
+------------+------+-------+
| 2020-01-01 | C    | 70    |
+------------+------+-------+
| 2020-01-02 | A    | 102   |
+------------+------+-------+
| 2020-01-02 | B    | 82    |
+------------+------+-------+
| 2020-01-02 | C    | 65    |
+------------+------+-------+
| 2020-01-05 | B    | 81    |
+------------+------+-------+
| 2020-01-05 | C    | 70    |
+------------+------+-------+
| 2020-01-05 | D    | 20    |
+------------+------+-------+
```

that I want to transform into the following format:

```
+------+------------+------------+------------+----------+
| Item | Date From  | Date To    | Value From | Value To |
+------+------------+------------+------------+----------+
| A    | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-02 | 100        | 102      |
+------+------------+------------+------------+----------+
| B    | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-02 | 80         | 82       |
+------+------------+------------+------------+----------+
| C    | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-02 | 70         | 65       |
+------+------------+------------+------------+----------+
| A    | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-05 | 102        | NAN      |
+------+------------+------------+------------+----------+
| B    | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-05 | 82         | 81       |
+------+------------+------------+------------+----------+
| C    | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-05 | 65         | 70       |
+------+------------+------------+------------+----------+
| D    | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-05 | NAN        | 20       |
+------+------------+------------+------------+----------+
```

So transforming a "series" of values into a range format, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this. I've tried using the shift operator but can't quite get it right. Some points to note:

- Items can enter and leave over periods - I don't care what value they get as long as there's a row representing them
- There will be a large number of value fields that must all be pivoted.
- The primary key of this set will include additional columns (i.e. not just Date & Item)

Some help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you know how to join 2020-01-02 and not 2020-01-01 in this row -> `| D    | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-05 | NAN        | 20       `

Comment: It should use the previous date in the list of unique dates (from the first frame) after they've been sorted ascending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let

```
data = [
    ['2020-01-01', 'A', 100],
    ['2020-01-01', 'B', 80],
    ['2020-01-01', 'C', 70],
    ['2020-01-02', 'A', 102],
    ['2020-01-02', 'B', 82],
    ['2020-01-02', 'C', 65],
    ['2020-01-05', 'B', 81],
    ['2020-01-05', 'C', 70],
    ['2020-01-05', 'D', 20],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'Item', 'Value'],)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Fill the missing previous dates for items that are there only one time:

```
dates = sorted(set(pd.to_datetime(df['date'].values)))

value_counts = df.Item.value_counts()
single_items = value_counts[value_counts==1].index
for item in single_items: 
    last_date = df[df['Item']==item]['date'].iloc[0]
    previous_date = dates[dates.index(last_date) - 1]
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([[previous_date, item, np.nan]], columns=['date', 'Item', 'Value']))
```

Join the data and drop/rename unneeded columns

```
dates = sorted(set(pd.to_datetime(df['date'].values)))

df['next_date'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: dates[dates.index(row['date']) + 1] 
    if dates.index(row['date']) != len(dates) - 1 else None,
    axis=1
)
df2 = df.copy()

result = df.merge(df2, left_on=['next_date', 'Item'], right_on=['date', 'Item'], how='left')
result.drop(columns=['date_y', 'next_date_y'], inplace=True)
result.rename(columns={
    'date_x': 'Date From', 
    'next_date_x': 'Date To',
    'Item_x': 'Item',
    'Value_x': 'Value From',
    'Value_y': 'Value To'
}, inplace = True)
result = result[['Item', 'Date From', 'Date To', 'Value From', 'Value To']]
result.dropna(subset=['Date To'], inplace=True)
result.sort_values(['Date From', 'Item'])
```

Result:

```
  Item  Date From    Date To  Value From  Value To
0    A 2020-01-01 2020-01-02       100.0     102.0
1    B 2020-01-01 2020-01-02        80.0      82.0
2    C 2020-01-01 2020-01-02        70.0      65.0
3    A 2020-01-02 2020-01-05       102.0       NaN
4    B 2020-01-02 2020-01-05        82.0      81.0
5    C 2020-01-02 2020-01-05        65.0      70.0
9    D 2020-01-02 2020-01-05         NaN      20.0
```

Comment: If it works for you don't forget to vote and accept (: